# How do I graph a vector with a variable on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I graph something that looks like this (3x^2+5,4x) , I usually use GeoGebra to graph this but I can't put a domain it should look like this (GeoGebra)[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the graph, you seem to be taking 3x²+5 on the horizontal axis and 4x on the vertical axis and hence:

```
x = -5.5: 0.01: 5.5;
plot(3*x.^2+5, 4*x, 'r');

%other minor adjustments to match with the graph in your post
grid on;    grid minor;    %to display grid lines
set(gca, 'XAxisLocation', 'origin');  %setting x-axis location to 'origin'
legend('eq2'); %to display the legend
```

which gives:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6ilI.png]

Comment: Can I assign this equation to a parameter so that when I call it , it recalls the equation for example : y=(3x^5+5 , 4x) and when I want to plot this equation I write plot(y)

Comment: @Youssef Are you asking something like this?  `x = -5.5:0.01:5.5;  y={3*x.^2+5, 4*x};  plot(y{:});` It may be better to define your custom [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Answer (score -2):

Something like this should do it:

```
y = -10:0.1:10;
x = 3 * y.^2 + 5.4 * x;

plot(x, y)
grid on
```

Comment: This is wrong you just graphed x=3y^2+5 and this gives wrong outputs